# Buffer loop with Python QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, loop

I want to iterate a buffer from a list of distances I have, but I can´t find the way to do it. I´m a beginner on Python.

```
import processing
x=[100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
processing.run("native:buffer",\
{'INPUT':'C:/Path/points.shp',\
'DISTANCE':x,\
'SEGMENTS':5,\
'END_CAP_STYLE':0,\
'JOIN_STYLE':0,\
'MITER_LIMIT':2,\
'DISSOLVE':False,\
'OUTPUT':'"C:/Path/Buffer" + str(x) +".shp"'})
```

Comment: You want to run the `processing.run()` for each of the values in your list `x` (bad name!). This should help you Google. If not, it is suitable as a Python question at stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a loop:

```
import processing
for x in [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]:
    processing.run("native:buffer",\
      {'INPUT':'C:/Path/points.shp',\
       'DISTANCE':x,\
       'SEGMENTS':5,\
       'END_CAP_STYLE':0,\
       'JOIN_STYLE':0,\
       'MITER_LIMIT':2,\
       'DISSOLVE':False,\
       'OUTPUT':'"C:/Path/Buffer" + str(x) +".shp"'})
```